# What happens if a file with server-side code is deleted while being executed?

Tags: java, php, python, terminal, server-side

If I write the following script (not just in php but **any server-side language really**):

```
<?php
  while (true)
  {
      sleep(4)
  }
?>
```

and I then run the file with the linux terminal like so: `php file.php`

**QUESTION:** What would happen if I delete the file itself? Was the process first stored in ram, and now is executing regardless of the existence or non-existence of `file.php`, would the process stop abruptly, or would something entirely different happen?

Comment: I think it is not possible to delete a used file. But why you do not try it

Comment: @Jens I plan on trying it when I Install a LAMP stack (XAMPP) on my laptop in a weeks time. As of right now I don't have a sandbox to play with. It would be cool though to understand what is happening in the backend, which is the purpose of the question: `What are the sequence of events that take place?`. Even after performing the test, I doubt the results will be enough to infer everything that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's already running, then it's already been loaded into memory, parsed and compiled, so it's running in memory.... deleting the file won't change that.... this is how compiled languages work, and contrary to many people's opinions, PHP is a compiled language.... it's compiled at execution time, and compiled to bytecode rather than to native machine code; but is still compiled nontheless

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Windows, but in Unix based systems the following applies:

If a program (like php) opened a file descriptor (e.g. by opening the file and executing/interpreting the content) the file will remain in existence until the file descriptor is closed. However, the kernel will prevent programs from obtaining new file descriptors after it was removed, and then delete it "for real" when the last descriptor is closed.

In the case of PHP it is most likely like Mark said in his answer. PHP will consume the entire file in one go, and then run from memory. But given the above it will sill work fine even if the file is removed while the process is busy reading it.

For more info see the following man pages: [unlink(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink) and [open(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)